# visual studio can't apply clang-format 13

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm expecting to use **AlignArrayOfStructures**, however it's only available in clang-format 13. So I set Custom clang-format.exe to `C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-format.exe`.

```
PS C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin> .\clang-format.exe --version
clang-format version 13.0.0
```

But I still got a error, it says [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the manual carefully.

> AIAS_Right (in configuration: Right)

`AIAS_Right` is the enum value, corresponding name in the config is `Right`. Use

```
AlignArrayOfStructures: Right
```

Answer (score 0):

vs2019 clang-format version ->12.0.0
[image]

vs2022 clang-format version ->13.0.0
[image]

**AlignArrayOfStructures: Lefe/Right** required 13.0.0
[image]